# How to add media='screen' in css using cakePHP?

Tags: css, cakephp

```
<?php
    echo $this->Html->css(
        array(
            '/printPlugin/css/960',
            '/printPlugin/css/screen',
            '/printPlugin/css/print',
            '/printPlugin/src/css/print-preview'
          )
        );
?>
```

This code produce following HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/demo-home22/printPlugin/css/960.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/demo-home22/printPlugin/css/screen.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/demo-home22/printPlugin/css/print.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/demo-home22/printPlugin/src/css/print-preview.css" />
```

My expected output is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/demo-home22/printPlugin/css/960.css"  media="screen"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/demo-home22/printPlugin/css/screen.css" media="screen"  />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/demo-home22/printPlugin/css/print.css" media="print" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/demo-home22/printPlugin/src/css/print-preview.css" media="screen"/>
```

That means I would like to add `media="screen"` in each CSS link.

N.B: I am using cakePHP 3

Comment: Do you meaning media attribute ? like as media = "print" ?

Comment: Yes. I mean media attribute.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here you can use

```
<?php echo $this->Html->css(['mycss'],['media' => 'print']); ?>
```

Output will like this html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/myproject/css/mycss.css" media="print"/>
```